# How to display some data in front Angular from Java backend with http

Tags: java, json, angular, typescript, http-get

I'm creating an application with Angular frontend and Java backend and i want to display data from the backend (json), how can i do?

I created an arrayjson in my Java code, then i'm displaying the array on a JSP page (on localhost8080) with a servlet. Then i'm doing an http get in my typescript to get the array, finally i'm displaying the data with a ngfor in my html.

Java creating json array :

```
public static JsonArray afficherClients() {
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = MongoMain.getDB().getCollection("Clients");

    FindIterable<Document> iterDoc = collection.find();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Iterator<Document> it = iterDoc.iterator();
    JsonArray array = new JsonArray();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        array.add(gson.toJson(it.next()));
    }
    System.out.println(array);
    return array;
}
```

Displaying on the server :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/json");  
    request.setAttribute("someData", Clients.afficherClients());
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("test.dispatcher.forward(request, response);  
}
```

The typescript in the front end to get data :

```
clients: Clients[] = [];

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get<Clients[]>("http://localhost:8080/my-app/test").subscribe(result => {
        this.clients = result;
    }, error => alert("Erreur"));
}
```

The HTML who's showing the entire array :

```
<ul class="list-group-item-heading" *ngFor="let client of clients; let i = index">
    {{ client }}
</ul>
```

I can have this kind of result with my code :

> {\"timestamp\":1557130609,\"machineIdentifier\":11848616,\"processIdentifier\":5812,\"counter\":8628551},\"nomEntreprise\":\"test\",\"rue\":\"test\",\"codePostal\":\"test\",\"ville\":\"test\",\"titre\":\"test\",\"nom\":\"test\",\"prenom\":\"test\",\"telephone\":\"test\",\"email\":\"test\"}"]

I created only 1 record in my array.

But i want to show only the name, or only the email, like {{client.email}} in my HTML but its not working.

So i expect something like (name + nickname for this example) :

test test

And not all of the data.

Comment: Hello. You said that ```client.email``` doesn't work. Can you show the error message?

Comment: Hi, the problem is that i dont have any display and no error message in the console

Comment: But json which you show doesn't contain ```name``` field

Comment: Yes sorry i translated it, with client.nom it's not working anyway

Comment: Are you looked into browser console (for google chrome it's F12 button to open)?

Comment: Yes i don't have any error message in the console

Answer (score 0):

You can easily debug, check the output with using *ngFor. just add in html:

```
{{ clients | json }}
```

If you find the json is comming correct you can then write code as:

{{ client.name }}

Comment: The {{ client | json }} works, but i cant use {{ clients.something }}, i don't have any display with that

Answer (score 0):

```
https://json.org/example.html
"{\"timestamp\":1557130609,\"machineIdentifie...."
```

As shown in the above excerpt, your code has slashes. It is not properly formatted JSON.